Microsoft.Powershell.SDK always requiring System.Management.Automation of one version lower
I am trying to build a visual studio extension that needs to make some calls to powershell (.NET 8 c# out-of-process VS2022 Preview).
I am adding a nuget package reference to Microsoft.Powershell.SDK and try to instantiate Powershell.
using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create(initialSessionState)) 

If I reference version 7.4.5 of the SDK, during runtime I get the error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=7.4.4.0
If I instead reference version 7.4.4 of the powershell SDK, during runtime I get the error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=7.4.3.0
And so on...
I can't add a reference to the missing Automation package since the powershell SDK already references a higher version.
Does anyone know why this happens and how I can remedy the issue?

Have your tried the different approaches explained here: https://dev.to/masanori_msl/execute-powershell-scripts-in-c-1gi4

Also there seems to be a raised issue regarding versions of that package. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/24110
